# problems with video player flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new in Flutter and try to load video from api, but video player is not working correctly. I have PageView in my Widget _buildFilmsMainPages() and each Page will get own video from api.

1. i'm getting error while data is loading: The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState>#033d3):
   The method '[]' was called on null.
   Receiver: null
   Tried calling:

After loading this error is gone.

2. when i tap on play (Floating Action Button) i see only first frame of video but sound is working.
3. when i tap on stop (Floating Action Button) first frame of video is gone but sound is still working.

   ```
     class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
     HomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
    final String title;

    @override
    _ HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
   }

    class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

    VideoPlayerController _controller;
    Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;
   bool isVideo = false;
    int filmIndex = 0;

    @override
     void initState() {
     super.initState();
    }

     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold (
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
         child: _buildFilmsMainPages(),
         )            
     );
   }


      Widget _buildFilmsMainPages() =>
        FutureBuilder( 
           future:getMoviesListByDay(date))),
         builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
   ```

   without this code i get error, but player isn't working 
   correctly anyway and i'm getting error while data is loading

   ```
         _controller= VideoPlayerController.network
            (snapshot.data[filmIndex].media!=null? 
             snapshot.data[filmIndex].media.elementAt(1)
             :"https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api- 
              docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4");
            _initializeVideoPlayerFuture =_controller.initialize();
            _controller.setLooping(true);



        if (snapshot.data != null) {
         return
          Column(
          children:<Widget> [
            SizedBox(
             height: 460.0,
              child: PageView.builder(
                pageSnapping: true,
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                onPageChanged: (int index) {
                setState(() {
                  filmIndex = index;
   ```

   i thought i should write this code here

   ```
                  _controller = VideoPlayerController.network
                   (snapshot.data[filmIndex].media!=null? 
                   snapshot.data[filmIndex].media.elementAt(1)
                      :"https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api- 
                    docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4");
                  _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = 
                       _controller.initialize();
                  _controller.setLooping(true);




                 });
                },
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                   return Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                       Container(margin: const 
                       EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                         child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                          child: Container(
                           height: 250.0,
                           child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                             child: GestureDetector(
                                 child: isVideo ?
                                 FutureBuilder(

                               future:_initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
                                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                   if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                         ConnectionState.done) {
                                       return AspectRatio(
                                         aspectRatio: 16.0 / 12.0,
                                    child:VideoPlayer(_controller),
                                       );
                                     } else {
                                       return Center(
                                           child: 
                                 CircularProgressIndicator());
                                     }
                                   },
                                 ) :
                                 FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                                   placeholder: 
                              "assets/placeholder.jpg",
                                   image:
                                   snapshot.data[index].media!=null 
                     ? snapshot.data[index].media.elementAt(0): "",
                                   fit: BoxFit.fill,

                         fadeInDuration:Duration(milliseconds: 50),
                                 ),
                                 onTap: () =>

                                           )
                                       ),
                                     )
                             )
                             ),
                               Row(children: <Widget>[
                                 Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0,
                                   right: 16.0, top: 190.0),
                                     height: 40.0,
                                    width: 40.0,
                                     child: FittedBox(
                                child: FloatingActionButton(
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                    foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                                        onPressed: () {
                                        setState(() {
                                         isVideo = !isVideo;
                                   if (_controller.value.isPlaying) {
                                           _controller.pause();
                                         } else {
                                           _controller.play();
                                         }
                                        });
                                        },
                            child: Icon(_controller.value.isPlaying
                                   ? Icons.pause : LineIcons.play,
                                       size: 30.0,)
                                  ),
                                )

                      );
   ```

Comment: Hi sk777, welcome to StackOverflow! You mention that there is an error and that the code is "not working correctly." Can you be more specific? Including the expected/desired behavior vs the actual behavior and the stack trace of the error message would be useful in helping to answer your question. This information should be included as an edit in the original question.

Comment: hi, Brydenr, thank you, i refined my question